# A solution to modify the aggregate function to work in vegetation analysis table

Tags: r, group-by, formula

I am working on a vegetation metrics data set and I have used the aggregate function successfully to obtain information per site. For instance I used

```
aggregate(Tree ~ ID, data=Calc_height_treesVI, FUN=mean)
```

to obtain the mean tree height ("Tree") from a set of subplots-within one plot location ("ID"). Because there are over 10,000 lines and variable amounts of heights per plot this was useful creating a new object with the mean tree height per plot location.

Now I want to do the same to obtain a measurement Diameter at Breast Height (DBH) per individual tree. Because many trees might have more than one stem there are more than one DBH entries per individual. There is a formula to obtain the DBH per individual. It involves obtaining the square root of the sum of all squared trunk stems. As an example:

+------+----+-----+

| Plot | Id | DBH |

+------+----+-----+

|    1 | A  | 5.4 |

|    1 | A  | 4   |

|    1 | A  | 3.9 |

|    1 | A  | 3.7 |

|    1 | B  | 4.3 |

|    1 | B  | 3   |

|    1 | B  | 3.5 |

+------+----+-----+

By hand you would get that the DBH of the individual of species A has a DBH of 8.60 after running the formula. Because there are multiple entries (with individuals of variable amount of stems) I would like to do this with R. But I haven't been successful at applying an appropriate formula directly. I found a solution but it took multiple steps. Here I share the steps:

```
DBH_individualsII$sqr <-(DBH_individualsII$DBH)^2 ##This squares each DBH and it creates the new column with that value "sqr"

DBH.add=aggregate(sqr~Id, data=DBH_individualsII, FUN=sum)##add the squared DBH by groups in this case the individual species

DBH.final=sqrt(DBH.sums.perind$sqr)##Make the final calculation by taking the square root of the added squared stems original DBHs
```

My question is, is there a more effective way ? Additionally, are there vegetation analyses packages that take into consideration this calculation of multi-stems DBH? I've tried reading through "vegan" and "ade4" so far without success but maybe Im not looking hard enough.

Thanks for your attention and patience, hope this can also help others out there working through vegetation data.

Comment: You need to post a sample of the data set you're using.  This will help to clarify your question and also give folks some data to use in developing a solution.

Comment: @WaltS I tried the answer from @Laterow and it worked. Thanks for both your replies and observations on how to post here.  Just as an example with a sample as you suggest.  `Id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")`     `DBH=c(4.3,4,3,5.6,7,3,3.2,3,6,2.9,8)`     `dat=data.frame(Id,DBH)`       `DBH_total=aggregate(DBH ~ Id, data=dat, FUN=function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an anonymous function in `aggregate`:

```
# Create some sample data
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(Id = rep(1:4,each=4), DBH = sample(1:16))

# Run aggregate with anonymous function
aggregate(DBH ~ Id, data=data, FUN=function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))

  Id      DBH
1  1 16.91153
2  2 21.33073
3  3 15.81139
4  4 22.47221
```